# Надо ли использовать forms.py в django3.0?

Tags: python, django

у меня возник вопрос, надо ли использовать forms.py в django3.0?

Comment: Если нужно... В любом случае, `forms.py` никогда не обрабатывался `Django`. Просто программистам было удобно выносить формы в отдельный файл и импортировать из него.

Comment: Никто не заставляет.

Answer (score 1):

Это же гораздо удобнее, чем просто прописывать формы в шаблонах. Появляется какое-то разграничение: шаблоны в одном месте, вьюхи в другом, формы в третьем. Поэтому используй (все равно решать тебе)